# angularjs check if 2 promises have returned

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-promise

I have a situation where I want to do things as each individual promise returns, and do something else when Both have returned.

```
promise1.then(function() { // do stuff })

promise2.then(function() { // do stuff })

$q.all([promise1, promise2]).then(function () { 
   var dependsOnBoth = promise1.x && promise2.x;
})
```

I'm wondering whether repeating the promises repeats the calls, and if there is a better way to just make sure that both have finished.  Thanks!

Comment: No, using `all` is perfectly fine for this, only I'm not sure what you mean by `promise1.x` and `promise2.x`. Always use the callback arguments!

Comment: ya that's a mistake.  in my case promise1 is a service that returns a promise, and promise2 is an api call.  I want to do something when each returns, and when both return, and don't know the best way to go about it

Comment: Of course you must not do `apiCall().then(x); apiCall().then(y)`, but need to use `var promise = apiCall(); promise.then(x); promise.then(y)`. *Create* it once, *use* it multiple times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you are calling **then** on each promise and again in $q.all on both promises. Each promise gets called twice.

**Option one:**
You would know, when each promise is resolved. So, don't call then on each promise. Only call it in $q.all.

```
var promise1 = function(){
 var promise1defered = $q.defer();

    // promise1 is resolved here.
    promise1defered .resolve();

   return promise1defered .promise;
}

var promise2 = function(){
var promise2defered = $q.defer();

    // promise2 is resolved here.
    promise2defered .resolve();

    return promise2defered .promise;
}

$q.all([promise1, promise2]).then(function () { 
  // Both promises are resolved here
})
```

**Option two:**
Instead of using $q.all, go for chaining promises.

```
var promise2 = promise1.then(function(){  


     // promise1 completed 
    // Resolve promise2 here
]);

promise2.then(function(){  

    // promise 2 completed
    // Both promise 1 and promise 2 are completed. 

});
```

Comment: If the promise objects are actually just promises (and not methods that return promises) there's nothing wrong with calling .then multiple times on them. `foo = Promise.resolve('yay'); foo.then(bar1); foo.then(bar2);` would just end up having bar1 and bar2 called, in that order, exactly once.

Comment: Please fix your first example, `promise1` and `promise2` are functions there not promises.

Answer (score 0):

Then functions resolve in the order that they're added to the promise, so the individual thens will be called before the all.then is called. Each then will only be called once, so that's probably the best way to handle that.

Of course, you could always put all that post-proccessing just in the all route, since it'll happen after both.

Also: don't forget your error callbacks.